# Is there a way to automatically pull from my git repo and restart my discord bot

Tags: python, git, ubuntu, github, discord.py

so i want to host a discord bot, and my friend is going to help me program it, we are gonna be using github as expected, i was wondering if github had a thing like whenever theres an upload in the repo the code gets changed on my ubuntu laptop on which im going to host it and whether it could restart the bot whenever theres an update to the repo or is there or is there any external application which will allow to host it

i havent tried anything yet as im clueless and new on how to do all this, i have also checked google and have found nothing.

Comment: I think you will find this medium article very helpful: https://oozio.medium.com/serverless-discord-bot-github-based-cicd-e2a9e9a7bc4d

It describes how to use github workflows to continuously redeploy changes to a discord bot whenever the repository is updated. This may not fit your exact usecase (this author uses AWS lambda, not a personal laptop) but it might be a good starting point!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to go about this. Firstly, I would create GitHub Releases each time you create a new working version of your bot. After you've done that, you can make a bash script on your Laptop to automatically check the current version of the GitHub release, and pull the latest if it doesn't match.

```
#!/bin/bash

REPO_URL="https://github.com/username/repo.git"
LOCAL_DIR="/path/to/directory"

cd "$LOCAL_DIR"

git pull
```

Make sure you `chmod +x` this to make it executable.

Then you can edit your `crontab` file by running `crontab -e`, and add the following line:

```
0 9 * * * /path/to/pull_repo.sh
```

Which, for example, will run it every day at 9am.

Alternatively, you could host the Discord Bot in a Google Cloud instance or AWS, and use GitHub Workflows to redeploy changes whenever the repo is updated.

Comment: Cron expressions can be confusing at first, there are online generators to simplify them! For example: https://crontab.cronhub.io/

Comment: hey so i researched a bit and can heroku do this aswell? I saw heroku and it pretty much removes all the headaches